# How can you show that $\int_3^\infty f(y)dy \lt \infty $ where $f(y)=\frac{e^y}{y^y}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can you show that $\int_3^\infty f(y)dy \lt \infty $ where $f(y)=\frac{e^y}{y^y}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{e^y}{y^y}\le\frac{\left(\frac{ey}3\right)^y}{y^y}=\left(\frac e3\right)^y$$

which holds for all $y\ge3$

Comment: Oh, whoops.  :P  My bad.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$e^y \leq \left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^y y^y$$ for any $y\geq 3$. So $$\int _3^\infty e^y y^{-y}\,dy \leq \int _3^\infty \left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^y\,dy=\int _3^\infty \exp\left(y \log\left(\frac{e}{3}\right)\right)\,dy=\frac{e^3}{27 (\log (3)-1)}$$